# ruby one-liner for this possible?

Tags: ruby, named-scope, activemodel

Any chance the 2nd and 3rd lines can be combined in an one-liner and hopefully save one valuable?

```
def self.date_format
  record = find_by_key('strftime')
  record ? record.value : "%Y-%b-%d'
end
```

the above function in a `Config` model try to fetch a database record by a key, return a default if not found in database.

Even better if can be written in named scope. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested.

Nobody yet has mentioned [try](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#objecttry), which is perfect for this situation:

`value = find_by_key('strftime').try(:value) || "%Y-%b-%d"`

Comment: Though `try` is not defined in ruby so you'd have to add `require 'active-support'`

Comment: question is tagged with `named-scope` and `activemodel` so was assumed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
(find_by_key('strftime').value rescue nil) || "%Y-%b-%d"
```

though using exceptions is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
value = find_by_key('strftime') || "%Y-%b-%d"
```

work for you?

Comment: sorry, return should be `reocrd.value`, not record

Comment: it's missing the `.value` call, but you can change it to `find_by_key('strftime').try(:value) || "%Y-%b-%d"` to keep it one line easily enough.

Comment: @x1a4, can you put it in an answer? such that I can credit you

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to assign a "value" variable at all? If not...

```
def self.date_format
  find_by_key('strftime') || "%Y-%b-%d"
end
```